# Using mutate with if/else if/else statements to create multiple new variables

Tags: r, conditional-statements, tidyr, dplyr

I would like to create a new variable/variables (depending on whether the data are in wide or long format) based on if/else if/else statements. I'm familiar with using mutate but cannot seem to get it to work for multiple variables. I see that there have been a number of similar posts on this and have tried the solutions offered but without success.

Here is a sample of the data in wide format:

```
structure(list(distribution = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("bimodal", 
"extreme_left", "extreme_right", "left_skew", "right_skew", "trunc_norm_left", 
"trunc_norm_right", "trunc_uni_left", "trunc_uni_right", "uniform"
), class = "factor"), Rating_1 = c(25L, 15L, 15L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 18L, 5L, 9L, 25L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 13L, 7L, 11L), 
    Rating_2 = c(0L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 0L, 
    11L, 10L, 1L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 5L), Rating_3 = c(0L, 
    4L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 20L, 10L, 0L, 16L, 8L, 0L, 14L, 26L, 5L, 
    16L, 6L, 20L, 8L, 13L, 9L), Rating_4 = c(0L, 8L, 6L, 19L, 
    19L, 11L, 13L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 0L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 13L, 10L, 
    10L, 8L, 12L, 9L), Rating_5 = c(25L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 
    15L, 18L, 5L, 15L, 25L, 7L, 2L, 34L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 13L, 8L, 
    16L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is one of the strategies I tried:

```
df %>%
  arrange(distribution) %>%
  if (distribution == "bimodal") {
    mutate(Dist1 = Rating_1 * 20 - 5,
           Dist2 = Rating_2 * 20 - 0,
           Dist3 = Rating_3 * 20 - 0,
           Dist4 = Rating_4 * 20 - 0,
           Dist5 = Rating_5 * 20 - 0)
  } else if (distribution == "extreme_left") {
    mutate(Dist1 = Rating_1 * 20 - 0,
           Dist2 = Rating_2 * 20 - 0,
           Dist3 = Rating_3 * 20 - 1,
           Dist4 = Rating_4 * 20 - 2,
           Dist5 = Rating_5 * 20 - 6)
  } else if (distribution == "extreme_right") {
    mutate (Dist1 = Rating_1 * 20 - 6,
            Dist2 = Rating_2 * 20 - 3,
            Dist3 = Rating_3 * 20 - 1,
            Dist4 = Rating_4 * 20 - 0,
            Dist5 = Rating_5 * 20 - 0)
  } else if (distribution == "left_skew") {
    mutate (Dist1 = Rating_1 * 20 - 1,
            Dist2 = Rating_2 * 20 - 1,
            Dist3 = Rating_3 * 20 - 2,
            Dist4 = Rating_4 * 20 - 2,
            Dist5 = Rating_5 * 20 - 4)
  } else if (distribution == "right_skew") {
    mutate (Dist1 = Rating_1 * 20 - 4,
            Dist2 = Rating_2 * 20 - 2,
            Dist3 = Rating_3 * 20 - 2,
            Dist4 = Rating_4 * 20 - 1,
            Dist5 = Rating_5 * 20 - 1)
  } else if (distribution == "trunc_norm_left") {
    mutate (Dist1 = Rating_1 * 20 - 0,
            Dist2 = Rating_2 * 20 - 0,
            Dist3 = Rating_3 * 20 - 6,
            Dist4 = Rating_4 * 20 - 3,
            Dist5 = Rating_5 * 20 - 1)
  } else if (distribution == "trunc_norm_right") {
    mutate (Dist1 = Rating_1 * 20 - 1,
            Dist2 = Rating_2 * 20 - 3,
            Dist3 = Rating_3 * 20 - 6,
            Dist4 = Rating_4 * 20 - 0,
            Dist5 = Rating_5 * 20 - 0)
  } else if (distribution == "trunc_uni_left") {
    mutate (Dist1 = Rating_1 * 20 - 0,
            Dist2 = Rating_2 * 20 - 0,
            Dist3 = Rating_3 * 20 - 4,
            Dist4 = Rating_4 * 20 - 3,
            Dist5 = Rating_5 * 20 - 3)
  } else if (distribution "trunc_uni_right") {
    mutate(Dist1 = Rating_1 * 20 - 3,
           Dist2 = Rating_2 * 20 - 3,
           Dist3 = Rating_3 * 20 - 4,
           Dist4 = Rating_4 * 20 - 0,
           Dist5 = Rating_5 * 20 - 0)
  } else {
    mutate (Dist1 = Rating_1 * 20 - 2,
            Dist2 = Rating_2 * 20 - 2,
            Dist3 = Rating_3 * 20 - 2,
            Dist4 = Rating_4 * 20 - 2,
            Dist5 = Rating_5 * 20 - 2)
  }
```

I tried this both with long and wide format data, although I realise that there is something missing for the long format data.

I'm looking for something like this if the data are in wide format.

```
structure(list(distribution = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("bimodal", 
"extreme_left", "extreme_right", "left_skew", "right_skew", "trunc_norm_left", 
"trunc_norm_right", "trunc_uni_left", "trunc_uni_right", "uniform"
), class = "factor"), Rating_1 = c(25L, 15L, 15L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 18L, 5L, 9L, 25L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 13L, 7L, 11L), 
    Rating_2 = c(0L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 0L, 
    11L, 10L, 1L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 5L), Rating_3 = c(0L, 
    4L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 20L, 10L, 0L, 16L, 8L, 0L, 14L, 26L, 5L, 
    16L, 6L, 20L, 8L, 13L, 9L), Rating_4 = c(0L, 8L, 6L, 19L, 
    19L, 11L, 13L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 0L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 13L, 10L, 
    10L, 8L, 12L, 9L), Rating_5 = c(25L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 
    15L, 18L, 5L, 15L, 25L, 7L, 2L, 34L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 13L, 8L, 
    16L), Dist1 = c(495, 295, 295, 95, 95, 75, 75, 355, 95, 175, 
    495, 135, 35, 15, 95, 235, 95, 255, 135, 215), Dist2 = c(0, 
    160, 120, 80, 100, 220, 160, 140, 240, 120, 0, 220, 200, 
    20, 220, 200, 200, 160, 200, 100), Dist3 = c(0, 80, 180, 
    180, 260, 400, 200, 0, 320, 160, 0, 280, 520, 100, 320, 120, 
    400, 160, 260, 180), Dist4 = c(0, 160, 120, 380, 380, 220, 
    260, 140, 240, 240, 0, 220, 200, 180, 260, 200, 200, 160, 
    240, 180), Dist5 = c(495, 295, 275, 255, 155, 75, 295, 355, 
    95, 295, 495, 135, 35, 675, 95, 235, 95, 255, 155, 315)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are those constant values that you are subtracting from each column or is there some logic involved?. It would be helpful if you share data only in one format and show expected output corresponding to that. Currently, your wide, long and expected output don't match with each other.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. Yes, there is a logic and those are constants. The values vary depending on the distribution and the rating (1, 2, 3...). I have edited the shared data and just given in wide format.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution:

```
rating_vars <- str_subset(names(df), "^Rating_")
N_ratings <- length(rating_vars)

scalar_data <- data.frame(
  scalar = c(
    5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,6,6,3,1,0,0,1,1,2,2,4,4,2,2,1,1,0,0,6,3,1,1,3,6,0,0,0,0,4,3,3,3,3,4,0,0,2,2,2,2,2
  ),
  distribution = rep(
    c(
      "bimodal", "extreme_left", "extreme_right", "left_skew", 
      "right_skew", "trunc_norm_left", "trunc_norm_right", "trunc_uni_left", "trunc_uni_right", "else"
    ),
    each = N_ratings
  ),
  rating = rep(rating_vars, N_ratings)
)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(id = seq_len(n())) %>%
  pivot_longer(contains("Rating"), names_to = "rating", values_to = "rating_value") %>%
  left_join(scalar_data, by = c("distribution", "rating")) %>%
  mutate(
    Distribution = str_replace(rating, "Rating", "Distribution"),
    distribution_value = rating_value * 20 - scalar
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(id, distribution),
    names_from = c(rating, Distribution),
    values_from = c(rating_value, distribution_value)
  )

names(df) <- case_when(
  str_detect(names(df), "rating_value") ~ str_extract(names(df), "Rating_[1-9]+"),
  str_detect(names(df), "distribution_value") ~str_extract(names(df), "Distribution_[1-9]+"),
  TRUE ~ names(df)
)
```